# How to Display Download Progress in Alert Dialog box using Dio package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am Currently trying to download a file from URL using Dio Package. I can successfully download the file but I want to display the progress in an Alert Dialog and once Download is Successful Then it Should Display "Download Successful". I tried but couldn't find any solution

Packages I used are : Dio, Path_Provider and permission_handler.
my Code :

```
class WatchView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WatchViewState createState() => _WatchViewState();
}

class _WatchViewState extends State<WatchView> {


  final Dio dio = Dio();
  bool loading = false;
  double progress = 0;

  Future<bool> saveVideo(String url, String fileName) async {
    Directory directory;
    try {
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        if (await _requestPermission(Permission.storage)) {
          String newPath =
              "storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.appname.test./files/";
          print(directory);
          newPath = newPath + "folder";
          directory = Directory(newPath);
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        if (await _requestPermission(Permission.photos)) {
          directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }

      File saveFile = File(directory.path + "/$fileName");
      if (!await directory.exists()) {
        await directory.create(recursive: true);
      }
      if (await directory.exists()) {
        await dio.download(url, saveFile.path,
            onReceiveProgress: (value1, value2) {
          setState(() {
            progress = value1 / value2;
          });
        });
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future<bool> _requestPermission(Permission permission) async {
    if (await permission.isGranted) {
      return true;
    } else {
      var result = await permission.request();
      if (result == PermissionStatus.granted) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  downloadFile(String file1) async {
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
      progress = 0;
    });
    bool downloaded = await saveVideo(file1, "test.file_extention");
    if (downloaded) {
      print("File Downloaded");
    } else {
      print("Problem Downloading File");
    }
    setState(() {
      loading = false;
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var provider = Provider.of<ProviderModel>(context);
    return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 0.0,
            leading: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            child: Container(
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
            label: Text(
              'Download',
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.indigo[700],
            icon: Icon(Icons.download_rounded),
            onPressed: () {
              downloadFile(
               "Download URL,
              );
            },
          ),
          floatingActionButtonLocation:
              FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have implemented the same same thing in one of my open source flutter project. The repo is here -> https://github.com/TheAlphamerc/flutter_commun_app

Comment: To be specific this code can help you -> https://github.com/TheAlphamerc/flutter_commun_app/blob/86c43b3f8f04e44ed4cbb6c24f07f08d8d73e067/lib/cubit/post/detail/post_detail_cubit.dart#L294